# How to show, that $z(y+1)=4(y+1)$ is $z=4$ rigorously?

Tags: proof-writing

For context:

**Theorem.**
There is a unique real number $x$ such that for every real number
$y$, $xy+x-4=4y$.

**Proof.**
We show the existence by choosing $x=4$. Substituting it in gives.
$xy+x-4=4y+4-4=4y$.
Suppose there is another real number $z$ such that for every real
number $y$, $zy+z-4=4y$. Add $4$ to both sides gives $z(y+1)=4(y+1)$.
From this we see, that $z=4=y$. Thus $x=4$ is a unique solution.

---

By cases, it would be:

1. Case: $y \ne -1$: We divide both sides by $(x+1)$ and get $z=4$
2. Case: $y = -1$: Leads to $0=0$ which is true, but does it say anything?

---

The $y=-1$ case bugs me. I can see, that the solution must be $z=4$ but I am somehow not convinced by the proof by cases as the second case only leads to $0=0$ and says nothing about $z$. How could I show rigorously what I see?

---

*Source*: It is an exercise from "How to prove it" by Daniel J. Velleman. The exercise 3.6.2 is "Prove that there is a unique real number $x$ such that for every real number $y$, $xy+x-4=4y$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started your proof of uniqueness correctly, by writing "Suppose there is another real number $z$ such that for every real number $y$, $zy+z-4 = 4y$."  I think you then confused yourself by ignoring the phrase "for every real number $y$" in this sentence.  In your next step, you concluded $z(y+1) = 4(y+1)$, as if $y$ were a fixed number.  The correct statement would be that *for every real number $y$*, $z(y+1) = 4(y+1)$.  If something is true for every real number $y$, then you are free to plug in any value you please for $y$.  (See the explanation of using a given of the form $\forall xP(x)$ in Section 3.3 of *How To Prove It*.)  So you can simply set $y=0$ and conclude that $z = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* true that $xy+x-4=4y$ has a unique solution $x$ for every $y\in \Bbb R$. Indeed, for $y=-1$, **every** $x\in \Bbb R$ is a solution.

However, the Theorem is meant to say that there is a *unique* $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $xy+x-4=4y$ is true for *all* $y\in \Bbb R$. And this $x$ must be $4$, by considering  $y=0$. Any other $x$ would not satisfy the equation for $y=0$, i.e., would not satisfy it for *all* $y$. This shows it "rigorously".

Comment: So you are saying that the theorem is meant to say this: $\exists ! x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (xy+x-4=4y)$

Comment: I am sorry, could you use words? I think that theorems in books are still formulated in words. Let me try.  **Theorem:** There exists a unique real number $x$ such that the equation $xy+x-4=4y$ holds for **all** real numbers $y$.

Comment: Sorry - you are right. I guess in it is nearly the theorem: There is a unique real number $x$ so that for every real number $y$, $xy+x-4=4y$ is true. But then I have trouble distinguishing how the theorem differed from the corrected version, proposed by you.

Comment: I think it is clear now. There is no difference. May I ask in which language the Theorem is originally formulated? Do you have a link?

Comment: It is an exercise from "How to prove it" by Daniel J. Velleman. The exercise 3.6.2 is "Prove that there is a unique real number $x$ such that for every real number $y$, $xy+x-4=4y$." I have forgotten to add it to the question - I add it now...

Comment: "To see, that $x=4$ is unique, suppose $zy+z-4=4y$. This $z \in \mathbb{R}$ has also to be $4$, because any other $z$ would violate the case $y=0$."  - The solution of @dietrich-burde in my own words (as I understand it). Replacing the uniqueness proof from the original post.